# Application_Start ans Current Users

Tags: asp.net, events

I have this code from a learning book:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
public void Application_OnStart()
{
Application["CurrentUsers"] = 0;
}
public void Session_OnStart()
{
Application.Lock();
Application["CurrentUsers "] =
(int)Application["CurrentUsers "] + 1;
Application.UnLock();
}
public void Session_OnEnd()
{
Application.Lock();
Application["CurrentUsers "] =
(int)Application["CurrentUsers"] - 1;
Application.UnLock();
}
</script>
```

A few simple questions:

1) When is the Application start? 
E.g. I deploy a new Web Site to my IIS and hit start - is that the start? Or the time when the website is first called?

2) When will my CurrentUsers zero again? On IIS Restart? Never?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) When is the Application start? E.g. I deploy a new Web Site to my
>   IIS and hit start - is that the start? Or the time when the website is
>   first called?

No, these are not IIS events. These are your application events. The Application_OnStart event occurs before the [first new session is created](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ev_app_onend_onstart.asp) (when the Application object is first referenced).

> 2) When will my CurrentUsers zero again? On IIS Restart? Never?

When all sessions are ended. The Session_OnEnd event occurs [when the session ends (abandoned or times out)](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ev_sess_onend_onstart.asp).